# Sort by two sql-laravel fields

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a query in laravel that returns some records. between these records they return some names and dates.

In this case I have 3 names, and several dates for each name. If I order by name and then by dates, it orders the dates but the names are mixed. if I order by name, the dates are not in descending order.

how can I do?

this is my query, which returns fine. I just have to order them as I need them.

```
$selectAttributes = [1,2, 3];

$data = Facturas::select(
            'anio',
            'mes',
            'codCuenta',
            'op.nombre',
            'fechaHora',
            'cli.nombre',
            'cli.direccion',
            'lecturaAnterior',
            'lecturaTomada',
        )
 
            ->leftjoin('clientes as cli', 'Facturas.codCuenta', 'cli.cod_cuenta')
            ->leftjoin('operadores as op', 'op.cod_operador', 'codLector')
            ->where('Facturas.anio', $a)
            ->where('Facturas.mes',  $m)
            ->where('Facturas.ciclo', $c)
            ->whereIn('nombreArchivo', $selectAttributes)
            ->orderby('op.nombre', 'desc')
            ->orderby('fechaHora', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

I need the same names to be grouped together and the dates for that name to be in descending order. something like that.

```
nombre1   fecha  5
nombre1   fecha  4
nombre1   fecha  3
nombre1   fecha  2
nombre2   fecha  5
nombre2   fecha  4
nombre2   fecha  3
nombre2   fecha  2
nombre3   fecha  5
nombre3   fecha  4
nombre3   fecha  3.... etc.
```

would someone know how I can do it? I would appreciate it very much.

It currently looks like this:

```
nombre1   fecha  5
nombre3   fecha  5
nombre1   fecha  4
nombre3   fecha  4
nombre2   fecha  4
nombre1   fecha  3
nombre2   fecha  3
nombre2   fecha  2
nombre1   fecha  2
```

Comment: What does the order look like right now?

Comment: Which field refers to the first column in the output?

Comment: the first field op.nombre. and the second field fechaHora